# C# WPF XAML Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'EqualityConverter' Key being added: 'EqualityConverter'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am getting the following error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message='Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.' Line number '9' and line position '6'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=9
  LinePosition=6
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
  InnerException: System.ArgumentException
       HResult=-2147024809
       Message=Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'EqualityConverter'  Key being added: 'EqualityConverter'
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
            at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value)
            at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.SetKeys(IList`1 keyCollection, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.SetDeferrableContent(DeferrableContent deferrableContent)
            at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext.<Create_BamlProperty_ResourceDictionary_DeferrableContent>b__168(Object target, Object value)
            at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
       InnerException:
```

I have a ***C# Class Library***, called **ABC**, which contains some WPF (XAML) windows.
I have another ***C# Windows Application*** project, called **ABC Settings**, which has an **App.xaml** with the ***StartupUri*** pointing to one of the windows in the class library using the correct Pack URI format. The window class is located in a class library because it needs to be accessible from another ***Windows Application***, called **ABC Client**.

```
<Application x:Class="CLASS_HERE"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="pack://application:,,,/ABC;component/ABCWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

In the **ABCWindow.xaml**, I have a fully completed Window which I remember working a couple months ago (when launched from the **ABC Settings** project). **When the window is launched from ABC Client there are no runtime errors!**

At the top of the Window's XAML code, I have some converter definitions:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ui:EqualityConverter x:Key="EqualityConverter" />
    <ui:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

If I swap the ordering of the converters, so the **VisibilityConverter** comes first, then the error message says that the **VisibilityConverter** is the problem.

I was able to get rid of this specific error by wrapping the converters in a **ResourceDictionary** but then I encountered another error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message='Could not register named object. Cannot register duplicate name 'addButton' in this scope.' Line number '65' and line position '26'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=65
  LinePosition=26
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
  InnerException: System.ArgumentException
       HResult=-2147024809
       Message=Cannot register duplicate name 'addButton' in this scope.
       Source=System.Xaml
       StackTrace:
            at System.Xaml.NameScope.RegisterName(String name, Object scopedElement)
            at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.RegisterName(ObjectWriterContext ctx, String name, Object inst, XamlType xamlType, INameScope nameScope, INameScope parentNameScope, Boolean isRoot)
       InnerException:
```

I have the following code further down in the Window's XAML code:

```
<Button x:Name="addButton" Content="Add" Click="addButton_Click" />
```

It seems that the XAML parser/framework/whatever thinks that I have duplicated key and object names but I am positive that there aren't.
Like I said above, this window runs fine when launched from the **ABC Client**.

I have searched around on MSDN forums and random blogs. I have cleaned and rebuilt my entire solution. I have restarted Visual Studio and even manually deleted all of the temporary Visual Studio files.

I have made sure all of the files have the correct build types:

**ABCWindow.xaml** is a ***Page***.

**App.xaml** is a ***ApplicationDefinition***.

My guess is that there is something wrong with the **ABC Settings** project and the **StartupUri** and whatever internal mechanisms connect all of that together.

Anyone have any suggestions on what's going wrong?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Never  seen anyone use Pack URIs for `StartupUri`. Better remove that and load  and show the window in the `app.xaml.cs` code behind.

Comment: I did this and it worked. There are tons of tutorials about how to load windows from another assembly and they all say to use Pack URIs.
Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Yeah. You'd do us all a favor if you report  this  to Microsoft.